# Keep body scrolled at the bottom unless user scrolls up in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a program where the user types in something and then something outputs in the "console." The most recent entered thing stays at the bottom unless the user scrolls up

The body of my document seems to be where I can dd effects like hidden scroll to it. I read another post and used scrollTop and scrollHeight and it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
</head>
<body id = "scroll">
    <div id="game">
        <div id="console">
        </div>

        </div>
            <div id = "command-box">
                <div id = "cmd">
                    <input id = "command" onkeypress = "doAThing(event);">
                </div>

            
        </div>
    </div>    
    <script src = "variables.js"></script>
    <script src = "code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var input  = document.querySelector("#command");
var theConsole = document.querySelector("#console");
theConsole.scollTop = theConsole.scrollHeight;
var myScroll = document.getElementById("scroll");

    function doAThing(event) {
        var theKeyCode = event.keyCode;
        
        if(theKeyCode === 13) acceptCommand();
        setInterval(scrollUpdate, 1000);
    }
function scrollUpdate() {
    myScroll.scrollTop = myScroll.scrollHeight;
}

function acceptCommand() {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    if(input.value === "hi") theConsole.append("Hi!", p);
    if(input.value === "ping") theConsole.append("Pong!", p);
    
}
```

Comment: You could have a checkbox for "autoscroll" - it would be simpler.

Comment: What would I put for the value?